# jQuery in an external file doesn't seem to be working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to animate a number by counting up from 0 to that specific number

index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/animate-numbers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>You have saved:</h3>
    <span class = "Count">10000</span>        
</body>
```

js/animate-numbers.js:

```
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({
  Counter: $('.Count').text()
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function() {
    $('.Count').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
  }
});
```

And it's apparently not working. Any insight helps, thanks!

Comment: You can check your file path... or tell us about any errors you can see in your console :) Your script works ! But I suggest you use something like this : https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, figured it out. Turns out it's a bit complicated to used jQuery in Chrome extension popups, you will need to download a min file and include that in the head of HTML file